# Rleationship between Google Identity Services - Sign In with Google and User Authorization for Google APIs

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, openid-connect

I'm studying the Google document on "Google Identity Services" and seem to see two stories.  One is called "Sign in With Google" which presents an attractive button where a user can sign-in with their Google account.  The other is the Google Identity Services Authorization which grants an access token to make API calls.

What I am missing is whether or not there is a relationship between these two concepts/SDKs/functions.  My mind is saying that I want a pretty button on my web page that I can use to sign in (ala Sign in With Google) AND I want the click of that button to give me an access token that I can use to invoke Google APIs.  What I seem to be finding is that they are separate and discrete concepts with no obvious relationship between them.  Is that correct?

##### References

- [Google Identity Services JavaScript SDK - Authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview)
- [Sign in with Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview)

2022-06-26: Following a post from Blunt, I tried to add a hint but that didn't seem to make a difference.  Here is the code I have been using.  First, the index.html that loads the test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        data-callback="handleToken" data-auto_prompt="false">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-size="large" data-theme="outline" data-text="sign_in_with"
        data-shape="rectangular" data-logo_alignment="left">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JavaScript loaded in index.js

```
const clientId = "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
function handleToken(x) {
  debugger;
  const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: clientId,
    hint: "myemailaddress",
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
    callback: (response) => {
      debugger;
    },
  });
  client.requestAccessToken();
}
```

What I am finding is that I get a the button in the web page as desired ... I click the button, I am prompted to sign in to Google and then the debugger statement (the first one) in the `handleToken` function is reached.  The code progresses and then I am prompted to sign in to Google a second time.  It had been my hope that the first sign-in would have been sufficient and somehow context would be preserved for the authorization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the new Google Identity Service, the authentication (sign-in) and authorization (access to api's) are separated, but not entirely distinct.

I have an article that explains this, and a reference implementation for pure client-side solution. `npm install gothic` will get you that reference implementation.

But here are the details:

(1) The sign-in with Google gives you the pretty button. Signing in provides user information encoded in a JWT. But none of this provides an access token.

(2) To obtain the authorization, you need to drive a second, sequential process. To expedite this process you can use the email address from the sign in process as an optional `hint` parameter to the authorization library, but the first time the user accesses it, they will still need to go through an explicit authorization process, depending on what api's (scopes) you need to access.

With regard to authorization, there are two models:

(1) Token-based. This is the pure client-side version. With this, you ultimately provide your clientId, your API-key, the discovery uri and the scopes to the library, and you get back a 1-hour token, that authorizes use of the APIs your app needs. As I mentioned, this requires an explicit prompt to the user the first time, and is click-free thereafter. But you *will* need to renew that token every hour, or on each page refresh.

(2) Code-based. This requires you to have a server-side to your app as well. In this model, your client obtains a code from Google, and hands that to your server. Your server exchanges it for an access token and a refresh token, and thereafter uses the refresh token to obtain new access tokens.

The server-side, code-based model is the more secure, and can ultimately provide the better UX, but it is of course more architecturally complex.

If you have specific code you are trying to get working, feel free to share and we can help.

Comment: Thank you Blunt.  This sounds hopeful.  You mentioned an article, do you have a link to that?  I will look at the npm gothic as well.  If I sense you correctly, I can use the "Sign on with Google" button, get the JWT, from the JWT, get the email address and use that as a hint in the authorization.  I'm going to try that in my sandbox.  What I want to avoid is having the user "sign on twice".  My mind is saying I want to click the button and have the user sign-on and THEN be authorized.

Comment: I tried the test of specifying "hint" but it made no obvious difference  I have updated the question with more details and sample code.

Comment: The article is https://medium.com/p/seamless-api-access-with-google-identity-services-b9901009a8ce -- and the hint only prevents the need for re-selecting the account at authorization time on subsequent loads. The first time user still needs to sequentially sign on, and THEN authorize the api's you need. There is absolutely no way around it. Google has changed the model to make a worse user experience. It's also much slower than before, but I hope they will address this.

Comment: Looking at your code, I suspect you are initializing the token client before sign-in has completed; but I can't quite tell.

Comment: Howdy Blunt ... from my experiments, I have handleToken() function which is invoked at the end of the "Sign on with Google" flow.  It is invoked AFTER the first sign-on and is passed a JWT.  Within the handleToken(), I am then trying to invoke authorization and that is when the second prompt for authentication is happening.  I've stepped through it with debugger.  Reading DalmTo's response, I'm starting to think that these are unrelated stories and the "Sign on with Google" is one "thing" and the authorization is another "thing" and there is no relationship.

Comment: That's totally true, I have said the same thing; the relationship is that you can avoid the second account-selection screen by using the hint, and on subsequent visits you can use the hint to avoid unnecessary selection/re-authorization. But otherwise, each sub-library is independent of the other.

Answer (score 3):

To start with you need to understand the difference between two concepts.

Authentication and authorization.

## authorization

Authorization is the act by which a user who owns private data grants an application created by a developer to access their data.   Authorization is requested by showing a consent screen.  A user consents to the application accessing their data, the amount of access a user grants is designated by the scopes requested.

In the image below the application Google Oauth 2.0 Playground is asking me for permission to `See and download all my google drive files`.

[image]

I requested the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" scope when requesting authorization.

Authorization is Oauth2. it returns an access token and a refresh token.   Access tokens can be used to access api endpoints.  In this case the google drive api.  Access tokens are short lived and expire after an hour.  The refresh token can be used to request a new access token at any time when the user is off line.   This is why there is no way for an api to see if the entity preforming the call is actually the user who owns the data, it may infact be a third party application using an access token and refresh token to gain access to the users data.

You can grant an application access to your data and they can continue to request your data until you revoke that access.

## Authentication

Authentication on the other hand is sign in.  It is prof that the what made the call is in fact the user who owns the account.   They must have typed their user name and password or logged into their account. Or already be logged into their google account on their machine.  If you have two google accounts signed in like I do they you will be promoted for which user you would like to use.

So authencation authenticates or proves, that the user making the call is in fact the owner of the account the data resides on.  Authentication is something called Open Id connect and was built on top of Oauth2.

The scope that are `email, profile, and openid` either profile or openid is required email is optional. Open id connect basically gives you access to a users profile information. If you are using a library you wont normally see this scope its normally added internally.  If the only scope that is requested is a open id connect scope then the user will not see a consent screen.   In the call above I added profile scope so you can see it is also asking for access to profile data but its grayed out the user cant not accept it.

[image]

Open id connect returns something called an id token.  the id token is very short lived its around five minutes.   An id token is a jwt so you can use jwt.io to decrypt it. Within the jwt you can find a number of claims.  This claims give your application information about who the user is that just signed into your system.

Of note, name, picture, locale (language), and sub,  sub is the users internal user id on the calling authentication server.  So you can use the google sub id to link this users google account to your internal user storage.  Then when ever this user logs in using google you will know which user it is in your system by matching the id.

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "40740878192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "1172004532672775346",
  "at_hash": "Aa0FT7DLf38T_onVI_ca8g",
  "name": "Linda Lawton",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhroCYJp2P9xeYeYk1npchBPK-zbtTxzNQo0WAHI20=s96-c",
  "given_name": "Linda",
  "family_name": "Lawton",
  "locale": "en",
  "iat": 1656311886,
  "exp": 1656315486
}
```

## Note.

Sign-in will not grant you an access token unless you are able to add additional scopes to it, like drive, or calendar.  I have yet been able to figure out how to add additional scopes to googles new JavaScript web login library.

The thing is what exactly are you trying to do.  Do you want to log a user into your system. Or do you just want access to some private user data of theirs through one of googles apis?

Comment: Thank you DalmTo.   What I want to achieve is calling GCP APIs (specifically GCS) from a browser.  I have been able to achieve authorization using the https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview documentation and all works.  I then read further and found the "Sign in With Google" button technology.  What I want to achieve is the "Sign In With Google" button which, when pressed, will sign in the user and THEN initiate the process for authorization.  When I tried this, the "Sign In With Google" authenticated me but when I then tried authorization ... it wanted to auth again

Comment: Yes thats because its two different things.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the authorization flow to re-request for authentication, you need to add the `prompt` and the `hint` properties to the `initTokenClient` or the `initCodeClient` method config object (depending on which one of them you use - see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/choose-authorization-model#choosing_an_authorization_flow)).

Here is how it looks like:

```
    google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
          callback: 'YOUR_CALLBACK',
          hint: 'THE_USER_EMAIL',
          prompt:''
        });
```

As mentioned, the same is true for `initCodeClient`.

In the same way, you can pass those properties not only on initialization phase, but on the event phase as well, with the `requestAccessToken` or `requestCode`, respectively. Here it is:

```
    googleClient.requestAccessToken({
                    prompt: '',
                    hint: 'THE_USER_EMAIL'
                });
```

In this code, `googleClient` is a JS const that stores the Google `codeClient` / `tokenClient` object.

**Explanation:**

- The `prompt` parameter with empty string tells Google to not request authentication if the user is already authenticated. This will let the flow to continue right to the authorization phase.
- This is not enough, because if there is more then one account connected to the browser, Google can not decide to WHICH one of them he should ask for authorization API. This situation will cause the authentication popup to show again, in order to let the user to choose an account.
- This is where the `hint` parameter comes to play, it lets Google to know what accont to use, then, if this account is already connected, Google is able to pass the entire authentication popup and go right away to the authorization one.
- In order to get the user email, you should use the `credential` property, returned from the authentication API of `google.accounts.id.initialize`. This credential is a JWT string, after decoding it with the JS `atob` method, you'll be able to extract the user email from it, beside other properties. For more details regarding to this, please check [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button#credential_handling).